# Stripe JS SDK, Where to put credit card infomration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

[image]

I made a custom card form, but i dont understand where i should put the card details (card number, cvc, exp. dat, etc). The client has already obtained the client_secret, but where do i put the card details?

I know this isnt 100% programming related, but I dont understand the documentation properly.

[Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment)

Comment: You don't. Stripe keeps that at their end, you just get a token that corresponds to it.

Comment: I made a paymentIntent so the token does not refer to any card details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are in the `cardElement`, which you need to have set up.  https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Comment: Do I have to use stripes prebuilt card element? Or can i just use my own?

Comment: You need to use Stripe's element in order to benefit from the PCI compliance shifts of Elements. https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance